# Not getting any results for video upload in Transloadit in c#

Tags: c#, transloadit

Am using transloadit for video converting and saving it in s3 in C#. I am able to upload the video and am able to get the response with empty results. My response had "ok": "ASSEMBLY_EXECUTING", message and the results tag is empty. So am not getting the final response once the assembly is executed. So, i see that there is some property assembly.setblocking = true.. but in C# that property is not available. So how can i get the final response.

Please help me out in solving this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In that first response, you should see an `assembly_url`. You can/should poll that URL every *X* seconds to get the updates. When the assembly reaches `ASSEMBLY_CANCELED` `ASSEMBLY_COMPLETED` `REQUEST_ABORTED`, or the `error` is set, it's done. I'm not sure if the boilerplate for this polling is implemented in the SDK, you'd have to check.

Blocking assemblies are not recommended as they require to keep the connection open, which is more brittle.